# Insert multiquery in NodeJS with PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to insert data into my database postgres. With simple query all is good but with the following query:

```
"INSERT INTO mytable (id, id_product) "+
"SELECT ($1, $2) "+
"WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM product WHERE id_product = ($2))",
[v1, v2]
```

I get the following error:

> 'The insertion source is a row expression containing the same number
>   of columns expected by the INSERT. Did you accidentally use extra
>   parentheses?'

How can I solve that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put parentheses around `($1, $2)`

Try this:

```
"INSERT INTO mytable (id, id_product) "+
"SELECT $1, $2 "+
"WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM product WHERE id_product = ($2))"
```